# Is it possible to do a multilevel conditional inheritance in python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, conditional-statements

Scenario -
Assume I have 4 classes - A, B, C1, C2

The main creates an instance of class A.
Class A is the youngest class whereas class C1 and C2 are at the same level but the eldest class. By young I mean child and by eldest I mean grand grand parent.

All classes are interlinked by multilevel inheritance, so the flow is
A --> B --> C1 or A --> B --> C2. Again A is child and it inherits everything from B and so on.

A set of parameters are passed when the main calls the instance of class A. Assume one of the parameters is flag.

Architecture

```
main():
   A(p1, p2, p3, flag)

class A(B):
   def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3, flag):
       B.__init__(self, p2, p3, flag) 

class B(C1, C2):
   def __init__(self, p2, p3, flag):
       if flag:
          C1.__init__(self, p2)
       else:
          C2.__init__(self, p3)
class C1():
    def __init__(self):
         self.fn_f1()

    def fn_f1():
       # Do something
class C2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fn_f1()

    def fn_f1():
       # Same function name, returns same type of variable but operations are different.
```

My problem is in the last part. Class C1 and C2 have the same function names and variables too, but do different tasks and produce the same structure in variables that are used in B and A as well. My code fails through this way and the error message indicates that when C2 is called, the C1's fn_f1 is being invoked. My inference is that this is due to multiple inheritances i.e. C1 gets higher preference as it is first inherited. I am not sure if my inference is incorrect, apologies if it is.

What I want is

```
class B(C1 if flag else C2):
   def __init__(self, p2, p3, flag):
       if flag:
          C1.__init__(self, p2)
       else:
          C2.__init__(self, p3)
```

But B doesn't know what is flag as it comes through parameters, so this doesn't work either.

Can anyone suggest what can be done? Please provide your solution with the central objective of inheritance and not instance creations. I know the below might work, but I want to inherit to avoid some other complications which I feel is irrelevant to state here.

Might work

```
class B():
     def __init__(self, p2, p3, flag):
         if flag:
            self.C1_obj = C1(...)
         else:
            self.C2_obj = C2(...)
      # Use the objects
```

The last one should work with ease, but as I mentioned, I really want to inherit due to other complications in A, B and so on.

Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The naive (read, first one I can think of) approach would be a generator function that returns the correct object.. why are you trying to do this?

Comment: While Python's syntax/grammar caters for and allows `class B(C1 if flag else C2):` (given that`flag` is defined at `B`'s definition time), this feels like a very bad practice and you should probably consider a different flow/design. Even having 2 different classes (one subclasses `C1` and the other subclasses `C2`) will be better and easier to debug

Comment: First of all you don't call the init method of the parent object, you use the super() keyword. Take a look at this link(https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_super.asp). Moreover, what is the error that you get?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have added more information on the error message.

Comment: @JeffUK How do I use generator function in such a case? Will it still be possible to keep the multilevel inheritance architecture intact? I will read up on generator function.

Comment: @ldall03, I avoided super here because the subclasses accept different parameters. And I think this way it is much cleaner to define what parameters does which subclass needs.